# Why am I getting problems with pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, tuples, pattern-matching, parse-error, custom-data-type

I am getting a parse error in my code and I don't know why. I can't see any problems with the code as it's the same syntax as pattern matching I have used in the past.

My code:

```
transaction_to_string (sob : unit : price : stock : day) :: Transaction
    | sob == 'S'   = "Sold " ++ (show unit) ++ " units of " ++ (show stock) ++ " for " ++ (show price) ++ " pounds each on day " ++ (show day)
    | sob == 'B'   = "Bought " ++ (show unit) ++ " units of " ++ (show stock) ++ " for " ++ (show price) ++ " pounds each on day " ++ (show day)
```

Where Transaction is a custom data type - Transaction = (Char, Int, Int, String, Int)

Error:

```
Parse error in pattern: transaction_to_string
   |
23 | transaction_to_string (sob : unit : price : stock : day) :: Transaction
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `:` is a `List` constructor, you probaby meant to use `,`

Comment: @cafce25 the : to my knowledge needs to be used for pattern matching, I tried it with the , instead and I still get the error.

Comment: A list is either an element (the head) and a list (the tail), which is match as `head : tail`; or the empty list, matched as `[]`. `sob : unit : price : stock : day` is senseless, because `day` is not a list, therefore I think you want to match on `sob : unit : price : stock : day : []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your code example.
try this instead:

```hs
type Transaction = (Char, Int, Int, String, Int)
transaction_to_string :: Transaction -> String
transaction_to_string (sob, unit, price, stock, day)
    | sob == 'S'   = "Sold" ++ (show unit) ++ " units of " ++ (show stock) ++ " for " ++ (show price) ++ " pounds each on day " ++ (show day)
    | sob == 'B'   = "Bought " ++ (show unit) ++ " units of " ++ (show stock) ++ " for " ++ (show price) ++ " pounds each on day " ++ (show day)
```

Comment: This did work now thank you but can you explain why in this scenario I need to use , instead of : I'm still not sure I understand the difference sorry.

Comment: Because you're matching a tuple `(a, b, c)`, not a List `[a, b, c]`

Comment: I wasn't aware it was different thank you.